How to Convert Missing Values to NULL in PySpark When Creating DataFrame from Pandas Without Additional Processing?
I am loading an Excel file into a Pandas DataFrame and then converting it to a PySpark DataFrame. However, I'm facing an issue where missing values (NaN) in the Pandas DataFrame are being interpreted as the string 'NaN' in the PySpark DataFrame, rather than as NULL.
Here is the code I'm currently using:
pandas_df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

I want to ensure that all missing values, such as None, NaN, NA, or nan, are directly converted to NULL when creating the PySpark DataFrame, without needing to apply extra transformations like:
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('column_name', when(col('column_name').isin(['None', 'NA', 'nan', 'NaN']), None).otherwise(col('column_name')))

I also tried replacing NaN values in the Pandas DataFrame with None before conversion:
pandas_df = pandas_df.where(pd.notnull(pandas_df), None)

However, this approach didn't work for columns where all values are 'NaN', and I had to run additional transformations, which is costly for my large dataset.
Is there a way to ensure that NaN values are directly converted to NULL when creating the PySpark DataFrame?

you could do the transformation in the pandas dataframe instead of the spark dataframe. alternatively, you could explore the na_values option in pandas.read_excel.

That extra transformation which you want to shave off doesn't seem to require extensive computation at all. That's a simple column expression, i.e. no shuffling, so not costly.
